# Do the different forms of precompilation impact performance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, precompile

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET4.5 and C#

There are a number of choices when precompiling a web application:

1. Do not Merge.
2. Do not merge, Create a separate assembly for each page and control.
3. Merge all outputs to a single assembly.
4. Merge each individual folder output to its own assembly.
5. Merge all pages and control outputs to a single assembly.

I am deploying to Azure websites.

I have currently opted for 3 which creates a 2.5MB assembly.

I realise that PCode is generated at this point ready for the Jitter to create the Native code at runtime, and therefore performance should be identical. However I was wondering whether there was still a performance difference between these options. I have currently chosen option 3, because it seemed tidier.

Thanks.

Comment: The only way to be sure is by profiling and benchmarking. What do your results say?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a performance impact based on your chosen merge option. How big? Uncertain without testing, but intuitively if there are more assemblies and files for your application to access, that should take longer than accessing a single assembly. My guess is the difference is minuscule. The assemblies themselves should not experience a performance impact, but your performance would suffer slightly in an un-merged scenario as there would be more files to process at run-time.

Additional resources that might help:

[Additional Precompile Settings Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh475319(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ASP.NET Merge Tool, Compilation and Merge Scenarios](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397866.aspx#Anchor_2)